# Set service repeat time within service

Tags: java, android, service

I'm starting a service with
`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, 60*1000, pendingIntent);`

Is it possible to set a new repeating time from within the service?

Also i tried to find information on how to stop a service from within without any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set a new repeating time from within the service?

Sure. Use `cancel()` to get rid of the original alarm, then schedule a new one.

> Also i tried to find information on how to stop a service from within without any luck.

Call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: Thanks, should have had more patience with the service documents.